# How to use Leaflet maps with aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, leaflet

I have just created an ASPX project and would like to integrate leaflet maps.

I have used leaflet before with HTML pages but now ASPX is requiring me to put everything inside a `<asp:content>` tag.

**My Code**

```
<asp:Content ID="MapPage" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-07I2e+7D8p6he1SIM+1twR5TIrhUQn9+I6yjqD53JQjFiMf8EtC93ty0/5vJTZGF8aAocvHYNEDJajGdNx1IsQ==" 
    crossorigin=""/>

   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-A7vV8IFfih/D732iSSKi20u/ooOfj/AGehOKq0f4vLT1Zr2Y+RX7C+w8A1gaSasGtRUZpF/NZgzSAu4/Gc41Lg=="
    crossorigin=""></script>


    <div id="mapid" style="height:100px; width:100px;"></div>

</asp:Content>
```

I took the link and script tags from http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

their tutorial... Also, VS17 says HTML5 doesn't recognize `crossorigin` or `integrity` fields... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this, this works for me.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm3" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
runat="server">

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-07I2e+7D8p6he1SIM+1twR5TIrhUQn9+I6yjqD53JQjFiMf8EtC93ty0/5vJTZGF8aAocvHYNEDJajGdNx1IsQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-A7vV8IFfih/D732iSSKi20u/ooOfj/AGehOKq0f4vLT1Zr2Y+RX7C+w8A1gaSasGtRUZpF/NZgzSAu4/Gc41Lg==" crossorigin=""></script>




<body>



<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);
```